# This.props.Values is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem about a page. In particular I have this value: `this.props.CategoriesList` That is a list about some categories. I have noticed that If I click a button which brings me to the page where it is used, this value is `undefined`. While If I refresh the page, this value is populated. Do you know how can I do to wait until this value is populated when I visit that page??

```
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    render()
    {
        const $Sender = $formConfig['$Sender']

        return(
            <Column col={'12'} className="my-4">
                <Row>
                    <Column col="12">
                        <Row>
                        <Column col={'md-12'}>
                        <Column col={'12'} className="mb-2" style={{padding: 20, border: '1px dotted #f5f5f5'}}>
                                    <Row>
                                        {
                                            $Sender.map((field, i) => {
                                                return(
                                                    <Column key={`$Sender_${i}`} col={field.col} m="b-3">
                                                        <Field {...field} component={this.props.preview ? Fields.ReadOnly : field.component} />
                                                    </Column>
                                                )
                                            })
                                        }
   //I used it there
                                        {
                                            this.props.CategoriesList && this.props.CategoriesList.length >0 &&
                                            <DataLinesAssociazioni CategoriesList={this.props.CategoriesList} formName={$formConfig.FORM_NAME} />
                                        }
                                    </Row>
                                </Column>
                            </Column>
                        </Row>
                    </Column>
                </Row>
            </Column>
        )
    }

}
```

EDIT: 
Parent:

```
_renderBtns(C)
  {
    return(
      <Row_DropDown id={C.Code}>

        <React.Fragment>
          <li>
            <A
              className="btn btn-link btn-sm mb-3"
              href={{ pathname: `${RoutesIT.products_edit}/${this.props.current._id}`}}>
              { 'Edit' }
            </A>
          </li>
```

Comment: strange, can you explain how the value is populated before passing to the component. Or may be react is not detecting the change in props, for this you can use spread operator, like `<MyComponent CategoriesList={...CategoriesList} />` , try this, this has saved me many times.

Comment: How should I use this component?

Comment: Anyway I used this.props.CategoriesList also in other page, an there it is populated (array of data) immediately

Comment: this is just a prototype, `this.props.CategoriesList`, here categorylist is passed as props to a component. You need to pass value to that component using spread operator.

Comment: I'm not so expert

Comment: Without knowing how you coded, I think no one can help. Keep trying, I was once like you, try hard

Comment: Props are passed down from a parent. `CategoriesList` must not be defined in the parent component which is passing it down in to the one you are showing us.  Can you show us the parent? Does the url change when you click this button (is it going through router)?

Comment: @TPHughes I have edited the question. Anyway yes, the url change

Comment: @Jack23 you are showing us the link to the new page. We need to see the upper level component which imports and uses the component you are having issues with. Ie: We need to see how and what you are passing `CategoriesList` as in the first place if we want to determine why it might be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Do chech like

```
 return(
   {
   typeof this.props!=="undefined" && <Column col={'12'} className="my-4">
            <Row> ...//Rest of code
   }
)
```

Comment: Try wrapping return in same kind of check (typeof) .

Comment: What I should obtain? Because nothing is changed :( 

I have print a console.log in the render and it prints like this: 
`this.props.CategoriesList undefined`
`this.props.CategoriesList (46) [{...`

Comment: yes I got it...it's because props is taking sometime to load(which is usual). So first when render happens there is no props value.Then after getting props it's showing value.So do like I have given in answer.

Comment: It doesn't change.. it doesn't show only the part about: 
`{
                                            this.props.CategoriesList && this.props.CategoriesList.length >0 &&
                                            <DataLinesAssociazioni CategoriesList={this.props.CategoriesList} formName={$formConfig.FORM_NAME} />
                                        }`

Comment: With your code the column and row should not be visibile if this.props. == undefined, but it seems to doesn't work